# What is a reasonable timeout for checking if a server is online?

Tags: python, udp, settimeout

I have to query ~10000 gameservers through an UDP protocol to check if they are online on a server every 15 minutes. My code is working, but servers that are offline block threads slowing progress down enormously. I use 20 threads, more will cause the UDP sockets of Python to slow down to a crawl.

Currently I'm using a five second timeout before deciding that the server is offline. Can this limit be further reduced, or must it even be upped?

---

Please don't suggest using heartbeats, my server is an unofficial masterserver for a game which has to leech and doesn't recieve most of the heartbeats.

Comment: You may want to add this to serverfault.com too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use synchronous communication (i.e. send packet, block and wait for results), especially not if you're using UDP. Just have one thread send out pings, and another one constantly receiving pongs on the same socket. If you have to do complicated processing with the results, you may want to use another one for that.

The challenge will be in the sending logic - you don't want to overwhelm your own internet connection, so I'd suggest a configurable rate of packets. Also, UDP packets can get lost in the network, so resend at least once or twice before giving up. As a timeout, I'd suggest about 2 seconds, because if a ping to game(i.e. highly delay-sensitive) server takes any longer than that, it's probably not usable anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I would love it if you would make it slightly more concise, but you don't have to. About the final part I'm not sure, because who am I to decide? My server is in Amsterdam and who knows what ping I have with an Australian gameserver?

Comment: @nightcracker Which part should be reduced? The distance between Amsterdam and Sydney is about 100 light-seconds. Assuming a 2x congestion, round-trip, and another 2x buffer, you're still only at 800ms, so I think 2s remains a good approximation. It *does not matter* though, you can safely set a timeout of 5min and everything will still work fine.